# How to edit json file data in React

Tags: json

I used json-server to receive data.

```
export const DataService = {
    async getAll() {
        const response = await axios.get('http://192.168.1.5:3001/plans')

        return response.data
    }
```

And received data

```
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async() => {
            const data = await DataService.getAll()
            setData(data)
    }

        fetchData()
    }, [])
```

Now I have a question, is it possible to somehow edit the data in the JSON file?